# Conditional server side + client side validation for complex models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation, client-side-validation

I have a model which is quite complex but in short it looks like this:

```
class ComplexModel{
 [Required]//default MVC
 string prop1 {get;set;}
 NestedModel {get;set;}
}
class NestedModel{
 [Required]//default MVC
 [StringLength(..)]//default MVC
 string prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

I want for example to run all `[StringLength]` validations on some post action let's say `SavePartially()` and run all kinds of validations on some other action `SaveFull()`.

If I had a flat model, I could have used some dummy property like `RunAllValidations` and use custom validation attributes like `RequiredIf` with a condition, but I have a complex model so don't wanna add such property to every nested model.

Is there any solution to create some sort of RuleSets which will work both on client and server side?

Or is it possible to define which validators will be applied on certain postback actions for the model?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a [custom validation rule/attribute](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC)

Comment: take a look at foolproof validation https://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Liam ok, but can you give a real example? besides, how to handle this on server side?

Comment: @DLeh OK, looks nice, but how to validate against rulesets on client side? can you a real example, please?

Comment: foolproof validation can work on client side with unobtrusive validation. i don't know enough about what you're trying to do to give a meaningful example. there should be plenty of other resources on how to use it.

Comment: @DLeh I want to use one model for 2 different post actions. Model properties will have validation attributes. So I want different to run some of the validations when going to the First action and all validations if going into the Second. It can be named like validation RuleSets. So I can mark [Required] attribute as RuleSet1 and ["StringLength"] attribute as RuleSet2. And for the first action run RuleSet1 validation, for the second RuleSet1 and 2 - both.
Also this should work on clientside. Some global RuleSet switcher should present.